# Как удалить модуль из приложения?

Tags: android-studio

Всем здравствуйте. Скачал Android Studio 3.0.1 Пробую написать приложение. Создал проект, например 1арр. В проекте создал новый модуль 1арр1. Не получается на пустом экране сделать поле с выводом даты. Решил удалить этот модуль 1арр1, чтобы начать все сначала.

Как удалить этот модуль, но оставить в системе всё то, что Android Studio подгрузил уже из сети?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить модуль можно таким способом, переходим `"File -> Project Structure"` либо правой кнопкой нажать на модуль и перейти в настройки модуля, дальше видим такую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выбираем ненужный модуль и удаляем. Модуля не будет в проекте, но его будет видно в project view, если же нужно удалить и файлы - выбираем модуль в project view и нажимаем на кнопку Delete. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710290/how-to-delete-a-module-in-android-studio) вопрос по вашей проблеме.